# Multi language cms with blog platform

Tags: content-management-system, blogs, translation, multilingual

One of my customers want to have a simple CMS/blogging platform.

I have experience with Sharepoint variations and that method is very good for him anyway he could not afford the cost of a Sharepoint for Internet license.

Which of the platform currently available have easy to use features for adding multilanguage content and handle its translations workflows?

Comment: specific platform or language? wordpress seems to be easier

Comment: @ajreal: None. I have mentioned sharepoint only to make a reference, for those who know it, to its translations facilities

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language

Comment: @ajreal: That's not the problem. The problem is related to having the same content in different languages with an easy to use translation workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned Sharepoint, I am assuming you are looking for a .NET solution.

If that is the case, take a look at [Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/), an open source CMS.

Comment: Does Umbraco need a professional license to be deployed?

Comment: No. See the [license page](http://umbraco.org/products/license)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a good cms php & mysql with blog you can use doorGets CMS, it's very easy to install and use, http://sourceforge.net/projects/doorgets-cms/files/latest/download?source=files

Answer (score 1):

[Drupal](http://drupal.org) has this built-in since version 6. The [i18n module](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) adds some advanced features as well.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress ) also has good support for i18n, and its admin interface is less complicated than Drupal's. You would need to use a 3rd party application (say, poedit http://dorkage.net/blog/2009/02/15/internationalization-work-flow-with-poedit/ ) to work with the translations, though.